# Dagger 2: Inject object loaded from database

Tags: android, database, singleton, dagger-2

I'm developing an Android app and use Dagger 2 to inject some objects as singletons in my activities/fragments. Some of the objects are loaded from database.

So is it possible to load the database object in the background and inject it as soon as it is available? Or is it no problem if I just load it when the singleton is initialized by dagger? Alternatively I just could pass the reference to the activities/fragments and load the object there.

What is your approach to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting question, because it touches on what I think is the first problem many people starting with Dependency Injection (DI) will face: what types of objects should I **inject**, what should I **new** up, and in your case, what should I pass around manually?

When you use dependency injection (and presumably also unit testing, but that's a different story), it's important that you understand the classification of the types of objects/classes you're designing:

1. Services: objects that perform some action, like business logic.

   - these are the things you'd want to [mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) in unit tests.
2. Value Objects (for the sake of our discussion, also includes [DTOs](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) and Entities.. think POCO or POJO): these are objects that hold information. Typically immutable model objects. Value objects don't have any dependencies on Services, i.e. you'd never want to inject anything into them.

   - You never mock these kind of objects in unit tests! You use concrete types and ideally [Test Data Builders](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestDataBuilder) to create them.

Note: these are my quick interpretation of these terms. If you read a book on [Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) you will find much more precise definitions, but I think this should suffice for the purpose of discussing DI.

[Misko Hevery](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/) (Father of AngularJS ;-) mentions that these terms, like "service" are overloaded, especially in Android, where "service" has a specific meaning, so he calls Value Objects and Services *Newables* and *Injectables* respectively. I think this is good advice.

To apply these concepts to your case: you'd have some class that queries the database for the object in question.

Let's say the object you're talking about is `Student` and it might have some immutable fields something vaguely like:

```
class Student {
    public final long id;
    public final String firstName;
    public final String lastName;
    public final String email;

    public Student(...) {
        // assignment of fields here...
    }
}
```

And then you'd have some object that queries `Student` entries from the database, let's say something like this `StudentRepository` here:

```
class StudentRepository {
    public List<Student> findAll() {
        // db access here...
    }
}
```

In this example, `Student` is a Value Object (newable), and `StudentRepository` is a Service (injectable).

In your code, you'd only want to use Dagger to inject the `StudentRepository` -- but you'd **never** inject a `Student`...

It's difficult to give further advice without knowing more details about what you're doing, but hopefully this answers your question: you'd have to pass the database Entity read from the database to wherever it's needed, you shouldn't have to inject it anywhere.

Comment: I store for example an user session in the database and want to pass it around as singleton. As I already have some kind of "Repository" (it's actually called service in my app ;) I will go with your solution and, instead of the session, inject the repository in my activities and load the session from there.